# About the folder for scripts

Tags: zend-framework

I'm at [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html) part of tutorial for zf1.

It says:

> At this point we have a connection to a database; in our case, its a connection to a Sqlite database located inside our application/data/ director..",

And then it shows an sql clause that I should save in a folder called `scripts`, but... where is that folder?

Comment: That part is related to SQLite (or creating your database) and simple SQL statements. It has nothing to do with Zend Framework but setting up a database. The path and filename is simply a reference to your database dump (or schema) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the folder if it doesn't already exist. Its location is not important as its contents are not used by your application directly, but by convention the folder would sit in the root of your app.

For reference, he's the recommended folder structure for a ZF1 application: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.project.html - the scripts folder there is the one on line 35. This is an extreme example - your application will likely have a lot less folders than shown in that guide.